# Kafka performance metrics with Prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, prometheus, jmx-exporter

I have two services (**serviceA** and **serviceB**), with two topics (`topicIn`, `topicOut`).

The flow of a  single message is as follows:

1. **ServiceA** produces a message to `topicIn`.
2. **ServiceB** consumes the message from `topicIn` and processes the message.
3. When **serviceB** has processed the message it sends it to `topicOut`.
4. **serviceA** then consumes from `topicOut`

I am looking for metrics to scrape with prometheus that will determine the time taken for **serviceB** to consume (`topicIn`), process and output the message (`topicOut`).

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: Can you do it programmatically? I think this is hard to use JMX metrics for this purpose.

Comment: Hey Giorgos, thanks for the reply. I may have to create and expose my own Java MBeans within serviceA. I can extract the amount of time all messages received from ServiceA, unfortunately serviceB is a black box so I was trying to determine metrics around its input/outputs